# "Right up one's alley?" Formal/in-formal?

Tags: idioms, formality

Is "Right up my alley" formal enough to use in a cover letter/job application etc? If not, are there any alternative idioms?

It sounded right to me and I was just about to use it in a formal document, but then I googled it and the first result was from urbandictionary, so I became suspicious.

Answer (score 7):

Do not use "right up my alley" in a cover letter.  A suitable substitute would be, "a perfect fit for me."

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use this term in a cover letter as it sounds a little cheeky and I'm guessing that that's not the impression you wish to make with a would be employer. ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right. It does sound cheeky. I was hoping for a formal alternative that's also idiomatic, but I didn't need one at the end...  I bet "Like a glove!!!" wouldn't have been appropriate either :P